# how to show checkbox in cell of table based on some condition

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with 5 columns and one of it's column say "Status" has only two values "Old" or "New". How do i show checkbox in column "Status" if value is "New.
If value is "old" checkbox should not be visible. I'm using angularjs.

if small example provided, it will be easy for me to understand.

thanks

Comment: What have you been tried so far?

Comment: i'm able to get checkbox for entire column .. not able to set the condition

Comment: First, are you using Angular, or AngularJS? These are two different frameworks. But anyway, both have an ng-if/*ngIf directive. This is extremely basic stuff, covered by any tutorial or book. Do some learning, and try something, before asking questions.

Comment: angularjs using

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf